# Plotting a Legendre Polynomial

Tags: plotting, special-functions

currently I am trying to plot for the Legendre polynomial $P_n(x)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$ and $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ .

To plot for it, I wrote the following code:

`MyLegendre=Table[[LegendreP[v,x],x],{n,0,4}]; Plot[MyLegendre,{x,-1,1},PlotLabels -> {"v=0", "v=1", "v=2", "v=3", "v=4"}]`

However, Mathematica keeps stating that there is an error with my above code. Any help to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `MyLegendre = Table[LegendreP[v, x], {v, 0, 4}]; Plot[
 MyLegendre // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"v=0", "v=1", "v=2", "v=3", "v=4"}]`

Comment: Thank you! The code now works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You need to reposition the labels

```
MyLegendre = Table[LegendreP[v, x], {v, 0, 4}]; 
Plot[MyLegendre, {x, -1, 1},
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabels -> 
  Placed[{"v=0", "v=1", "v=2", "v=3", "v=4"}, 
    {{Scaled[0.5], Above}, {Scaled[0.385], Above}}]]
```

[image]